# How to count unique values in a dictionary of lists with Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

So I have the following data that I'd like to use pandas to show the following output:

```
             MakeWheel  UpdateWheel  MakeGlass   UpdateGlass MakeChair UpdateChair ...
Toyota.         1            1           1            1          0         0
Mercedes.       2            0           0            0          0         0
Hyndai.         0            0           0            0          8         4
Jeep.           0            0           0            0          2         2    
...
```

The grouping is based on whether the keys match e.g. UpdateChair, or MakeWheel. If `Mercedes` we grouped them because the `MakeWheel` is the same, so we just merge them and count the items in both list, if the items are the same, include them as well, for example in `MakeChair` case, although `right` and `left` are the same items in the list, we would count them all, so we got 8 keywords (Make, Update) to show adjacent to each other.

The `cars_dict` is

```
{
    "Toyota": [
        {
            "MakeWheel": [
                "left-wheel"
            ]
        },
        {
            "UpdateWheel": [
                "right-wheel"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MakeGlass": [
                "right-wheel"
            ]
        },
        {
            "UpdateGlass": [
                "right-wheel"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Mercedes": [
        {
            "MakeWheel": [
                "left-and-right"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MakeWheel": [
                "only-right"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Hyndai": [
        {
            "MakeChair": [
                "right",
                "left"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MakeChair": [
                "right",
                "left"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MakeChair": [
                "right",
                "left"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MakeChair": [
                "right",
                "left"
            ]
        },
        {
            "UpdateChair": [
                "right",
                "left"
            ]
        },
        {
            "UpdateChair": [
                "right",
                "left"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Jeep": [
        {
            "MakeChair": [
                "left-and-right",
                "back-only"
            ]
        },
        {
            "UpdateChair": [
                "right-and-left",
                "left"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting wrong output.

```py
r_list = []
for car_k, car_v in cars_dict.items():
    for i in car_v:
        r = {k: len(v) for k, v in i.items()}
        r_list.append({car_k: r})

pd_list = []
for r in r_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r)
    pd_list.append(df)
df = pd.concat(pd_list, axis=0)
output = df.transpose().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the initial dictionary you provided, here is one way to do it:

```py
# Import data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cars_dict, orient="index")

# Transform dicts in Series and append as new columns
df = pd.concat(
    [df[col].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, dtype="object")) for col in df.columns]
).dropna(how="all")

# Deal with list of values
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.explode(column=col)

# Count values and cleanup
df = (
    df.groupby(df.index)
    .count()
    .reindex(
        index=["Toyota", "Mercedes", "Hyndai", "Jeep"],
        columns=[
            "MakeWheel",
            "UpdateWheel",
            "MakeGlass",
            "UpdateGlass",
            "MakeChair",
            "UpdateChair",
        ],
    )
)
```

```
print(df)
# Output
          MakeWheel  UpdateWheel  MakeGlass  UpdateGlass  MakeChair  UpdateChair
Toyota            1            1          1            1          0            0
Mercedes          2            0          0            0          0            0
Hyndai            0            0          0            0          8            4
Jeep              0            0          0            0          2            2
```

Comment: this is great thanks. One thing I don't know upfront is the list of cars types `index=["Toyota", "Mercedes", "Hyndai", "Jeep"]` they can be anything coming from API call. is there a dynamic way to process those?

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need them, it was just to get an output with rows and columns sorted as the one in your post, you can remove the `.reindex(...)` part entirely. Cheers.

Comment: yep! done. just accepted the answer.